# Getting XCOPY to concatenate (append)

Tags: windows-7, cmd

It it actually possible to get XCOPY to append, as per

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true
To append files, specify a single file for destination, but multiple files for source (that is, by using wildcards or file1+file2+file3 format).

?

Neither wildcards or file1+file2+file3 format works for me.

Workaround (sometimes): Use COPY instead.

Comment: In my test it will not append - only overwrite the destination file again and again.

Comment: @foxidrive, same here.

Comment: The + operator only applies to the /exclude command line option, supporting specifying a list of files.  Use superuser.com to ask these kind of questions.

Comment: @Hans "The + operator only applies to the /exclude command line option" The docs are wrong?

Comment: No, that's what it says when it explains what /exclude does.

Comment: "The + operator only applies to the /exclude command line option" "that's what it says when it explains what /exclude does". Actually I do not see it saying that in the explanation of /exclude or anywhere else. And I do see it saying "+" can be used in destination too.

Comment: The documentation in xcopy states `To append files, specify a single file for destination, but multiple files for source (that is, by using wildcards or file1+file2+file3 format)`, but, maybe, while updated, [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/114618) is applicable by design

Comment: @MC, Thanks. That indicates to my satisfaction that yes the doc statement quoted in my question is faulty.

Comment: The MS KB (Microsoft Knowledge Base) link posted earlier by @MCND doesn't work anymore, the latest I could find on Archive.org is http://web.archive.org/web/20150121081805/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/114618 which clearly states **XCOPY Does Not Merge Files** this is *by design in order for XCOPY for Windows NT to be compatible with MS-DOS 5.0* what a pity...

Answer (score 3):

If I get it right, you want to merge files into one. For text files I would use:

```
FOR /R %%f in (file*) DO TYPE %%f >> bigfile
```

Comment: Thanks. Be sure bigfile is empty first.

Answer (score 0):

The `copy` command supports concatenation natively:

```
copy <srcFiles> <destination>
```

It will list the files as it copies them, and the result will be in the target directory.  This is more efficient than using `TYPE` (which you could also achieve with `TYPE file* >> bigfile` for the @Diodak answer, rather than using `FOR` loop.

Example:

```
C:\Users\f1rum>cd %TMP%
C:\Users\f1rum\AppData\Local\Temp>echo test1 > xxx_test1.txt
C:\Users\f1rum\AppData\Local\Temp>echo test2 > xxx_test2.txt
C:\Users\f1rum\AppData\Local\Temp>echo test4 > xxx_test3.txt
C:\Users\f1rum\AppData\Local\Temp>copy xxx_*.txt merged.txt
xxx_test1.txt
xxx_test2.txt
xxx_test3.txt
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Users\f1rum\AppData\Local\Temp>type merged.txt
test1
test2
test4
```

Comment: This appears no longer to work in Windows 11, at least according to my tests.

Comment: @radfast example worked for me there. what are you doing different to what you see above?